# Snapshot version not changing in nodejitsu when deploying through github

Tags: node.js, github, nodejitsu

I think I've got things set up properly to deploy changes to nodejitsu through github commits, but changes to the version (in package.json) are not making their way through.  Upping the version and then deploying using 'jitsu deploy' works as expected (producing version 0.0.3 for example), but upping the version, committing, and pushing to github results in a deploy with the same version number (0.0.3-1 for example).

Not sure what I'm missing.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per a Nodejitsu support engineer, nodejitsu's github webhook has been having some problems, and they are looking into rewriting it.  He suggests using `jitsu deploy` for now.